# How can I invert y-axis controls for Just Cause 2 on the PS3? 

Tags: just-cause-2

Is there a way to invert the y-axis on the PS3 controller for Just Cause 2?

It is very annoying for me - I got into controls but there doesn't appear to be an option for this.

Comment: If it's not in the options, then my tentative answer is no?

Comment: Which stick are you talking about? Left or Right?